# Odd Number of elements in hash assignment in subroutine parameter

Tags: perl, hash, parameters

I want to pass a hash and `$dbh` to my sub `save2db`. However, I am getting an error message: `Odd number of elements in hash assignment in file2.pm` after this line of code: `my (%resultHash, $dbh) = (@_);`. Can someone please explain to me the cause of this error. Thanks in advance!

file1.pl

```
my $dbh_global = connect2db();
my %hash; ##Assume there are nothing wrong with the hash and it is populated

foreach my $fileName_input (@ARGV){
    NVD::save2db(%hash, $dbh_global);
}

sub connect2db{
    my $driver = "mysql";
    my $database = "test";
    my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:database=$database";
    my $userid = "root";
    my $password = "";

    my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password) or die $DBI::errstr;

    return $dbh;  
}
```

file2.pm

```
sub save2db{

    my (%resultHash, $dbh) = (@_); # <-Error message occured

    foreach my $resultHash_entry (keys %resultHash){
        my $a= $resultHash{$resultHash_entry}{'a'};
        my $b= $resultHash{$resultHash_entry}{'b'};
        my $c= $resultHash{$resultHash_entry}{'c'};
        my $d= $resultHash{$resultHash_entry}{'d'};

        my $insert_sql = $dbh -> prepare("INSERT INTO `test`.`record`
                                       (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`)
                                       VALUES
                                       (?, ?, ?, ?)");

        $insert_sql->execute($a, $b, $c, $d) or die $DBI::errstr;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Odd number of elements in hash assignment`  is not an error but a warning.
The problem rises because when the values are passed to the subroutine, the values gets flattened together.

Let us consider your hash have some data for example

```
%hash = ("a"=>1,"b"=>2);
```

and  `$dbh_global  = "abc"`

Then you pass the value into the subroutine,

```
 NVD::save2db(%hash, $dbh_global); #the problem is here.
```

Hash will always have a key with value. So every hash will have only even data.

you retrieve the value into the subroutine like,

```
my (%resultHash, $dbh) = (@_);
```

So `%resultHash`will contain uneven values, three keys and two values like this

```
{
  a=>1,
  b=>2,
  abc           #This is the reason of the warning. 
}
```

and then `$dbh` has no value in it.

so Change the line as

```
NVD::save2db($dbh_global, %hash);
```

and retrieve  the values into subroutine like

```
my ($dbh,%resultHash) = (@_);
```

Or else

use hash reference for to do it.

```
my $resulthash_ref = \%resultHash; #Hash reference 

NVD::save2db($resulthash_ref, $dbh_global);


#inside the subroutine 
{
    my ($hash_ref,$dbh) = (@_);
    my %hash = %{$hash};  #Dereference the hash
}
```